# What would be the best strategy to build an Angular Dynamic Form based on user request?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I have been reading the documentation on [Angular Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form), it seems very easy to work with them. But I am not sure what would be the best strategy to build a dynamic form based on the user request and on assets/fields that I should store on firebase/firestore database.

So, on firebase I have a document of assets that I will use to store information for my assets inventory, lets say (computers, desks, bicycle). So when the user selects an asset I should show the appropriate form.

My idea is that I should have the assets document and the fields document related by the asset uid, so I can ask for the specific fields I need from this database. Les say (Asset=title:computer,id:01)->(Fields=id:01,type:inputDate).
I understand that I will need to make a model for the inputDate Field.

What I am not sure is how could I tie the database data to showing a specific group of fields related to an asset for the form.

Can someone help me with the basic idea to jumpstart this forms, I am a bit lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked ngx-formly? It has the option to directly pass the json object also. https://formly-js.github.io/ngx-formly/

Comment: I will check it, thanks.

Comment: I suspect you'll still need to create yourself a configuration schema to configure each form. I've built many database drives forms in the past and there nearly always reaches a point where you need more flexibility than is available purely from the database store. So I would define a form scheme per asset, probably in JSON and use that to build your dynamic form.

Comment: do you want any dynamic validation in the schema? because I am designing a sample application to give you high-level idea of it.

Comment: Actually I do. Dates, numbers, text, custom, etc.

Comment: @moplin : I have answered another user about dynamic validation and json structure, can you please check and let me know how many other things you require in your expected solution. This is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140829/adding-dynamic-from-fields-that-changes-the-fields-sorting-and-validation-at-r/53145088#53145088